# How can i reuse Retrofit code in Android

Tags: android, retrofit, code-reuse

The following code is how i currently use `Retrofit`

```
Interface
**********

public interface LeafAPI
{

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ConstantValues.BaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofitScr = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(ConstantValues.BaseUrl)
            .build();


    @GET("someController/serviceName")
    Call<ArrayList<UserDetails>> getUserList();
}
```

Usage In `Activity`:

```
private void getUserDetails() 
{
    ServiceAPI api = ServiceAPI.retrofit.create(ServiceAPI.class);
    Call<ArrayList<UserDetails>> call=api.getUserList();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<UserDetails>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<UserDetails>> call, retrofit2.Response<ArrayList<UserDetails>> response) {
            //Process the result and display in the UI  
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<UserDetails>> call, Throwable t) {
            //Display Error Message
        }
    });
}
```

My situation is that i have to `fetch` the `userlist` in a number of `activities`.
so i have ended up duplicating the `getUserDetails()` method in each one.

I would like to know if it is possible to move `getUserDetails` to a seperate `Class` and then reuse it from there. I have looked around but all examples on `retrofit` follows something similar to what i i have placed above.

I would really appreciate any help that points me in the right direction.

Comment: yes you can use move it to separate class and re-use it and have callbacks to the activity

Comment: If your project grows, then maybe its time to use some architectural pattern (like MVP, MVVM). Check this simple example of using retrofit in an MVP project: [Simple MVP Retrofit example](https://github.com/jeancsanchez/Simple-MVP-Retrofit-example)

Comment: also i would suggest you to go through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t34AQlblSeE. You need not have retrofit and retrofitScr. For more info watch the video

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks i found the link very useful.Thanks

Comment: I dont understand the reason for the down vote, could someone point that out please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this what you can do is make one class called `GetListingUtility` and put this method in this `GetListingUtility` class.

**for ex :**

```
public class GetListingUtility{

Context context;
OnItemSelected onItemSelected;

public GetListingUtility(Context context, OnItemSelected onItemSelected) {
    this.context = context;
    this.onItemSelected = onItemSelected;
}

 private void getUserDetails() 
{
    ServiceAPI api = ServiceAPI.retrofit.create(ServiceAPI.class);
    Call<ArrayList<UserDetails>> call=api.getUserList();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<UserDetails>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<UserDetails>> call, retrofit2.Response<ArrayList<UserDetails>> response) {
            //Process the result and display in the UI  
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<UserDetails>> call, Throwable t) {
            //Display Error Message
        }
    });
}

}
```

then you can call this method like :

```
private void callGetCountriesWS() {
    GetListingUtility utility = new GetListingUtility(getActivity(), new OnItemSelected() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(Object kv) {
            // your stuff you want to do
        }
    });
    utility.getUserDetails();
}
```

Comment: `getUserDetails()` probably should be declared `public`.

Comment: @chandani c patel if i understand you correctly 'OnItemSelected' is a Interface, with a method    onItemSelected(Object kv). Is this correct.

Comment: @chandani c patel will it affect my memory usage if i change the getUserDetails() to static method and directly pass the context and Interface.

Comment: @Deepak do not use static methods if not necessary

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the `callback` itself to handle it on the `Activity`:

```
public class ApiCalls {
   public static void getUserDetails(Callback<ArrayList<UserDetails>> callback) {
       ServiceAPI api = ServiceAPI.retrofit.create(ServiceAPI.class);
       Call<ArrayList<UserDetails>> call=api.getUserList();
       call.enqueue(callback);
   }
}
```

On your `Activity`:

```
ApiCalls.getUserDetails(new Callback<ArrayList<UserDetails>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<UserDetails>> call, retrofit2.Response<ArrayList<UserDetails>> response) {
        //now you can  handle it on your activity, yey.
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<UserDetails>> call, Throwable t) {
        //Display Error Message
    }
});
```

Comment: i feel what you have suggested is not much different from my code , as we have to still rewrite getUserDetails(new Callback..  in all the Activities.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explained it well, the `getUserDetails()` will be generic, it will be written only on one `class`.

Comment: Please check updated code, if you don't want to Callback (because it is still big) we can add a custom interface to handle to list response.